# Trying to download threads from a forum that's shutting down, but HTTrack isn't saving images/menu/colors and page links correctly

Tags: images, download, styles, links, httrack

[NotebookReview](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/all-technologyguide-forums-will-close-jan-31-2022.837524/) is shutting down at the end of the month, and there are several threads in their forum that I want to download to my PC before all the information is gone forever.

I am trying to use [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) (actually WinHTTrack) to download the threads. For example, let's say I want to download this thread:

- http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/what-should-we-call-an-nbr-successor.837550/

This thread has multiple pages, and the URL for page 2 and beyond looks like this:

- http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/what-should-we-call-an-nbr-successor.837550/page-2

So I tell WinHTTrack I want to download the following address:

- http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/what-should-we-call-an-nbr-successor.837550/

Then under the Options > Scan Rules, I have the following to tell it to grab all images/javascript/css and all pages:

`+*.png +*.gif +*.jpg +*.jpeg +*.css +*.js  +forum.notebookreview.com/threads/what-should-we-call-an-nbr-successor.837550/page*`

Based on the log file, the exact command that is executed is:

`winhttrack -qiC2%P%xs0u1%s%uN0%I0p3DaK0H0%kf2o0A25000%f#f -F "Mozilla/4.5 (compatible; HTTrack 3.0x; Windows 98)" -%F "<!-- Mirrored from %s%s by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2014], %s -->" -%l "en, *" http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/what-should-we-call-an-nbr-successor.837550/ -O1 "C:\Users\username\Downloads\NotebookReview threads\Test" +*.png +*.gif +*.jpg +*.jpeg +*.css +*.js +forum.notebookreview.com/threads/what-should-we-call-an-nbr-successor.837550/page*`

When I check the output directory, I can see `index.html`, `page-2.html`, `page-3.html`, and `page-4.html`, so it is downloading all the pages.

However, when I try to load `index.html` in a browser with my network disabled, there is a problem with the images:

[image]

As you can see, the website logo and user avatars are not displayed on the page, but I see those images on my PC. When I do a "View Source" on the page, the website logo is `<img src="../../../cdn.ttgtmedia.com/techguide/forum/nbr/nbr_forum_logo.png" alt="NotebookReview" />`. When I click on `../../../cdn.ttgtmedia.com/techguide/forum/nbr/nbr_forum_logo.png`, the browser displays the image on my hard drive. So the browser can load the image from my hard drive, but not when displaying the HTML page for some reason.

Also, the browser isn't showing the menu bar and none of the background colors. I do see that some JS and CSS files have been downloaded to my hard drive.

In addition, the page links are incorrect. For example, the link for page 2 is pointing to:

- http://forum.notebookreview.com/page-2.html

But it should actually be pointing to:

- file:///C:/Users/username/Downloads/NotebookReview%20threads/Test/forum.notebookreview.com/threads/what-should-we-call-an-nbr-successor.837550/page-2.html

**What WinHTTrack configuration settings do I need to change to solve the following problems?**

1. The images are downloaded to my PC, but the browser is not displaying them on the downloaded web pages.
2. The menu bar and background colors aren't showing up.
3. The page links do not point to the HTML pages downloaded to my PC.

Comment: Try setting Maximum Mirror Depth and External Depth to 2 or higher.

Comment: @harrymc The Maximum Mirroring Depth and Maximum External Depth were blank, which means unlimited. However, I tried setting them both to 20, and that didn't help - the download pages are just like before.

Comment: You could perhaps try some [HTTrack Alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/httrack/).